# Creating a variable that combines other variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-variables

I am practicing SQL Server dynamic variables, and I encountered a problem here.

Suppose I have two dynamic variables:

```
declare @firstname varchar (200)
declare @lastname varchar (200)

set @firstname = 'select firstname from Person.Person'
set @lastname = 'select lastname from Person.Person'
```

My question is how can I create a 3rd variable `@fullname` that combines `@firstname` and `@lastname` to show the full name?

I tried the syntax like:

```
declare @fullname varchar (200)
set @fullname = @firstname + ' ' + @lastname 
exec (@fullname)
```

But it doesn't work, any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: You don't need the `exec`.  The `set` does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I print the list of fullname?

Comment: I think you mean `SET @FullName = 'SELECT FirstName + ''' ''' + LastName FROM Person.Person'`... but why? why you need to use dynamic SQL while you can avoid it?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve... What are you expecting to see stored in `@fullname`? Also to re-iterate what @Sami has said, avoid dynamic SQL if you can, especially if you aren't fully au fait with its use.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @fullname varchar (200)

Select @fullname  = firstname + ' '+lastname 
 From Person.Person
 Where ID={somevalue}
```

Comment: As OP said in a comment he want to print the list then how this query can achieve that using a variable?

Comment: You may be right John, but according to the code I think the OP trying to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your query simply as shown below. I do not think any specific reason for the variable if you want the list of first names and last name to be printed as you said in your comment.

It is because a variable can store only a single value at a time.

```
Select firstname + ' ' + lastname from Person
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable value with SET or in a SELECT statement. Either way you have to select that variable apart from the value assignment operation to see its value.

```
declare @firstname varchar (200)
declare @lastname varchar (200)
declare @fullname varchar (200)
declare @fullname2 varchar (200)

set @firstname = 'Mickey'
set @lastname = 'Mouse'

set @fullname = @firstname + ' ' + @lastname

select @fullname2 = @firstname + ' ' + @lastname

select @firstname as [FirstName]
     , @lastname  as [LastName]
     , @fullname  as [FullName]
     , @fullname2 as [FullName2]
```

Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95c2105650c1451899f89398603ac5bf).